# bxslider infiniteloop scrolls left to first slide instead of right to loop

Tags: bxslider

I seem to have a problem that I haven't seen reproduced elsewhere.

We have a slider on a clients' site (www.laparksfoundation.org). We have the slider set to infiniteloop = 1 (code below). The issue, is that when the slider reaches the last slide it doesn't continue to the right to show the first slide in the series, rather, it scrolls image by image to the left until it gets to the first one and starts again.

We've checked the code and the parameters seem ok, however, it jumps to the first one rather than scroll right to create a seamless loop.

The code is below, any help would be helpful

```
    $('.slider .bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager: false,
            auto: true,
            speed: 2000,
            pause: 12000,
            slideSelector:'.slider .bxslider li',
            infiniteLoop: true
    });
```

The images are displayed in a simple

:

```
   <div class="slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
          <li>
                 <img1>
                 <h2 class="txtImgHome" id="slide353">ENHANCE, EXPAND, PRESERVE AND PROMOTE</h2>
          </li>
          <li>
                 <img2>
                 <h2 class="txtImgHome" id="slide354">50 Parks Initiative, Bringing Parks to your Neighborhood</h2>
          </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

How would I make it so that when I reach the last image on the set, the next image is the first one and when I'm on the first one and click left the last image shows up without having the slider scroll all the way back?

Comment: It seems to be working. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9SNw/)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using an older jQuery library.
Initially I was using v1.11.0 and switched to v1.10.0 and everything worked perfectly.

You can load jQuery v1.10.0 from Google like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. The jquery file that comes with bxSlider is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Hello It works great with jQuery 1.8.3,  Check this

```
<ul class="bxslider">
      <li>
             <img1>
             <h2 class="txtImgHome" id="slide353">1</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
             <img2>
             <h2 class="txtImgHome" id="slide354">2</h2>
      </li>
          <li>
             <img3>
             <h2 class="txtImgHome" id="slide354">3</h2>
      </li>
</ul>
```

$('.slider .bxslider').bxSlider({

```
        pager: false,
        auto: true,
        speed: 2000,
        pause: 12000,
        slideSelector:'.slider .bxslider li',
        infiniteLoop: true,
        moveSlide:1
});
```